# CSS only working with direct link, why relative wont work?

Tags: html, css, web

Trying to build a webpage. and relative css link wont work. Only direct linking.

Head:

```
<link href="http://directorym.net/App_Themes/customDarkBlueWAdSense_en-US/customDarkBlueWAdSense_en-US.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://pboo.mobi/corey/articles_media/dmNet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://pboo.mobi/corey/App_Themes/mobile.css" />
```

test at http://pboo.mobi/corey

when i make it relative:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="articles_media/dmNet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="App_Themes/mobile.css" />
```

it wont show up.

Suggestions?

Comment: Abslute path could help you instead of relative path.

Answer (score 2):

Use the absolute path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/corey/articles_media/dmNet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/corey/App_Themes/mobile.css" />
```

Comment: Of course now that I've posted this it works either way. But I'll stick with the absolute. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need http:// on local files though and you were missing "/corey" in your path.

Comment: I know i dont need http on local files, which is why it was pissing me off.
but local path will also work with `href="App_themes/mobile.css"` without a leading "/corey/" as long as there's no slash ahead, since it's all local. it should've worked, but for a day, it wasnt.

Comment: Beware: If you prefix paths with "http://" and some pages end up using "https://" the user will get security warnings. A good reason to leave them out.

Comment: Paths with a leading slash are usually referred to as _root relative_, not absolute.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your site and changing page code on the fly with browser, they show up with both relative and absolute paths.

Anyway remember that relative means "relative to the current page path".

You have three options when it comes to url paths:

a) Absolute

```
href="http://www.mysite.com/myfolder/myfile.css"
```

b) Relative

```
href="myfile.css"
```

c) Absolute with forward slash instead of domain name

```
href="/myfolder/myfile.css"
```

Comment: entirely correct. And i was using the first 2 correctly at first. but it stil wasnt working. literally as soon as I post this, it started working again. I dunno what was happening.

still. sometimes some of the styles work, some dont. the background only works sometimes for some reason. not sure what's going on.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at the [base tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4)

Answer (score 0):

suppose the folders `articles_media` and `App_Themes`and the html page are all based in the same original folder. The header of the html page can then contain:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/articles_media/dmNet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/App_Themes/mobile.css" />
```

(note the `/` before the folder name)

Comment: ^this is actually incorrect. because that will take it back to the root folder. this is the only way that wont work. but this will work with
`href="/corey/App_themes/mobile.css"`
its going back and forth.

Comment: OK, but with 'the same original folder', I meant just that: the root folder.  yours/Diodeus answer allows placing the html outside the rootfolder, and I now understand that the css files are placed within a folder in the '/corus/' subdirectory, so you are right..

Answer (score 0):

To add to what people have said so far, also consider using the full path but using protocol relative links.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//pboo.mobi/corey/articles_media/dmNet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//pboo.mobi/corey/App_Themes/mobile.css" />
```

This way you won't have to worry about potential security errors with http:// or https://